# Setting 'current working directory' while communicating with the DLL via JNA

Tags: java, jna, native-code, native-methods

we're using `com.sun.jna` package to call methods from external library (DLL). This library uses some support/cache data (DAT files), which it writes in the 'current working directory'.
Unfortunately when we associate our file extension with our application (to open our files on double click in Windows), then the current working directory is set, to the directory of the file being open, and thus our DLL writes its cache data next to the opened file. That way if we open many files from different locations on an HDD we'll have our DLL's cache all over the system.
We would also want to control the place, where we save any cache/temporary/support data - and we do control that, except for the cache of the DLL in question.

Is there any way for me to set 'current working directory' for this DLL, while communicating with it via classes from `com.sun.jna`? Can I overwrite this setting somehow and pass it to JNA?

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.
Piotr

Comment: Does the library provide a way to change its working directory like an OS environment variable that stores a working path in the similar way JDK uses JAVA_HOME to find its Java bin folder?

Comment: You'll need to figure out how the DLL is deciding what the "current working directory" is.  It might be reading it from an environment variable (getenv), a system call (getcwd), or using the parent directory of the file.  See if you can use a system call tracer (dtrace/strace on linux) to see if it's using one of those.  That will let you know what you need to set/tweak in order for the DLL to get the "right" directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the jvm with `System.setProperty("user.dir","yourpath");`, but I don't know if that change will get inherited by the dll after the jna call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer - I've tried that earlier. Unfortunately setting this, doesn't change, what the DLL uses - it seems, the DLL reads current working directory from different source - probably some win32 function :-(. So I guess there won't be any way to change this?